# How to trace down to find where a field has been removed/hidden of a particular node

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, media

I am using a purchased theme provided by 3rd party (it is actually a custom Drupal build comes with their modules and theme). My problem is that image fields are hidden some where in the module(s) provided by this theme.

I am sure that the `apartment.field_image` is not removed in the template (neither by using any `hidden()` function nor by non printing the `$content['field_image']`. I came to this conclusion by observing the `$content` using Devel module as well as by using standard `dpm()` function. That field is just not there (node content) at all.

I have also made sure its not hidden in the display settings of this content type its "image".

I have checked rest of the code by searching for preprocess, `field_image` and image to see if they are manipulating it anywhere. I found many processor functions which were manipulating something else like adding css etc., but but I dint find any traces where they are hiding/unsetting/removing the field.

Please guide me how can I trace it. My mind is just blowing off. Thought I would get good sleep after a week but looks not the case.

Comment: some things to look at: make sure under display, that the type of display is set correctly (full content, teaser, default, etc). Check if field permissions or similar is installed and that the permissions for that field are set correctly. Check for any rules or actions that could be causing it to be removed.

Comment: another - is it in a field collection, display settings for those are shown under /admin/structures/field collections not under the content type

Comment: Hi. Have you built your site and subsequently applied the theme? I.e. you know that the image field should display on certain pages and you have some content - let's say pictures of apartments?

Comment: Geoff i will check. Iain, yes my image field is displayed in some views

Comment: Geoff, you answered it I guess. I checked only default display mode which was not hidden but in the full content mode it was hidden. I will test on Monday May be I will go office tomorrow :) . Thanks for the hint. May be you can add answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some things to look at: make sure under display, that the type of display is set correctly (full content, teaser, default, etc). Check if field permissions or similar is installed and that the permissions for that field are set correctly. Check for any rules or actions that could be causing it to be removed.

another - is it in a field collection, display settings for those are shown under /admin/structures/field collections not under the content type

Answer (score 0):

You may use DevTools in Chrome browser to find out how and from where the element has been hidden of a particular node, by setting the breakpoint on that element on subtree & attributes modifications or node removal in contextual menu as shown below:

[image: Break on: Subtree & attributes modifications or node removal]

Alternatively you may try [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) or [Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) which can show you debugging information about events that have been attached to DOM elements. See: [How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/446892/55075)